# subtract a pattern in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am trying to subtract a pattern in Elixir.

I have 2 file names as `30_01_000.jpg` and `30_00_000.jpg` in which 30 are minutes , 01 & 00 are seconds. What I am trying to achieve is to find the difference between them, as it's obvious, the difference is 1 second. But I could have one file as `40_01_000.jpg` and the other one could be `50_01_000.jpg`. So I want a dynamic way to do this.

The strategy behind this is: I requested a file for `30_00_000.jpg` (through actual timestamp in Unix) BUT the available one is `30_01_000.jpg` So If I will find the difference I can add it to Unix timestamp of the first file so It will get the next one available.

So is that possible to do so? in anyway? Any help will be thankful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need to decompose the strings into component parts:

```
iex(4)> <<minutes::binary-size(2),"_",seconds::binary-size(2),"_",milliseconds::binary-size(3),".jpg">> = <<"30_00_000.jpg">>

#=> minutes
#=> "30"
#=> seconds
#=> "00"
#=> milliseconds
#=> "000"
```

Then you'll want to convert the strings to integers like so:

```
minutes = String.to_integer(minutes)
```

Finally do your subtraction on the proper components of the time something like this:

```
difference = seconds_of_a - seconds_of_b
```

---

EDIT: I had a few minutes to write up a bit more complete answer:

```
defmodule T do
  def subtract_seconds(<<minutes_a::binary-size(2),"_",seconds_a::binary-size(2),"_",milliseconds_a::binary-size(3),".jpg">>, <<minutes_b::binary-size(2),"_",seconds_b::binary-size(2),"_",milliseconds_b::binary-size(3),".jpg">>) do
    String.to_integer(seconds_a) - String.to_integer(seconds_b)
  end
end

# You would call this routine like this:
# T.subtract_seconds(<<"30_10_000.jpg">>,<<"30_04_000.jpg">>)
# => 6
```